# How to set up dynamic on the fly angular routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I attempted to create routes on the fly in the following two ways inside the `ngOnInit` of the root component `app.component.ts`

```
this.router.resetConfig([
  { path: 'news/:article-slug', component: ArticleComponent },
  { path: 'pages/:page', component: StaticPagesComponent },
  ...this.router.config
]);
```

And

```
this.route.config.unshift(
  { path: 'news/:article-slug', component: ArticleComponent },
  { path: 'pages/:page', component: StaticPagesComponent }
);
```

But neither method work when I type in the URLs in the browser. They only work if the URLs are generated by `routerLink` and I click on them.

How can I generate dynamic routes that can be accessed by typing in the URL in the browser?

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of put your code ngOnInit you must put it in app.component constructor.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.config.unshift(
      { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
      { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component }
    );
  }
}
```

Regards